# Get real string length in emacs

Tags: string, emacs, character-encoding, yasnippet

What is the proper way to compute the actual string length in emacs?  By actual I mean I want the number of chars inserted into a buffer after doing something like `(insert "\nhi")` or `(insert "\x100")`.

For example, I have a snippet for writing `expand-abbrev-hook`'s but it doesn't get the string length right when there are escaped characters, eg.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: expand abbrev
# key: eah
# --
("${1:abbrev}" ["${2:pre}${3:post}" ${3:$(length yas-text)} nil nil] expand-abbrev-hook :system t)
```

The value computed in `$3` should land the cursor back between `$2` and `$3` after expansion, but if there are strings with `"\n"` for example, then length is off a bit.

Comment: `length` applied to a string gives you the number of its characters. `string-bytes` gives you the number bytes in its string argument. `string-width` gives you the number of columns used to display the string in the current buffer (with TAB chars interpreted as occupying `tab-width` columns).

Comment: @Drew ok thanks, so I would have to roll my own I suppose since `(string-bytes "\x100")` => 2 and `(string-width "\n")` => 0